# deleteOne from mongoDB with mongoose in object display page support

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

i am trying to remove a particular 'ticket' in this case from the database. the page displays a table of all the tickets and their seat name and price, and a delete button(form). However, the delete function (regardless of which one i select) only deletes the first ticket in the list.

here is controller function:

```
    Ticket.findOneAndDelete(req.params.id, function(err) {
      console.log('deleting button works in Tickets router')
        res.redirect('/tickets');
      });
    };
```

router:

`router.post('/tickets/:id', ticketsCtrl.delete)`

ejs snippet:

```
        <tr>
          <td><%= t.seat %></td>
          <td><%= t.price %></td>
          <td>
          <form id="delete-ticket-form" method="POST"
          action="/tickets/<%= t._id %>">
          <input type="submit" value="X">
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: ```Ticket.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.id}, function(err) {console.log('deleting button works in Tickets router');res.redirect('/tickets');});};```

Comment: hope it will work https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-shadow-2lzyq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Form post method does not make any sense if you are grabbing the value of id from url(query parameter).

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh using mongoose and express, its my understanding that i cannot simply delete or update, that i need to use a '?_method =' to be able to use those HTML properties, the middleware does not let Put and Delete requests

Answer (score 0):

the JS was correct, but i missed a closing  tag
*slaps head